# Order mysql data if I just have id's

Tags: mysql, sorting

I've got an intermediate table called Likes that is composed by the ID of a user and the ID of a picture, forming a composed primary key as it follows:

```
> show columns from Likes;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id_user | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| id_pic  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

My question is... if I select the id of a certain user, is any possibility of order his id_pic's by the moment they where inserted?

I mean, if I insert the values `(id_user,id_pic)`:

```
1,1
1,3
1,6
1,2
```

How could I obtain the values of `id_pic` for the user 1 in reverse order as they were inserted? (If it's possible..)

Thanks!

---

EDIT: I know that if I have an id for the table I could order by that id, but i'm NOT allowed to change the structure of the table :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following using [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) and an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM likes 
ORDER BY id_user ASC, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_user) DESC;
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cc027a73ac2a2e759cafaa3228575df)

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to open another question, so... how could I also show a column from the Pics' table?

Comment: @Ommadawn - you can use a `JOIN` (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`)